# Update column "X" if any changes made within A:AE range, but keep the same row

Tags: excel, vba, range, offset

I am trying to create a code that would update a date value in column "X" should there be any changes in any cells within A:AE. Update function must only work for the same row. For example, I make a change to A1 and X1 is updated. Many thanks!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 Dim R1 As Range
 Dim R2 As Range
 Dim InRange As Boolean
    Set R1 = Range(Target.Address)
    Set R2 = Range("A:AE")
    Set InterSectRange = Application.Intersect(R1, R2)

  InRange = Not InterSectRange Is Nothing
     Set InterSectRange = Nothing
   If InRange = True Then
     R1.**Offset(0, 1)**.Value = Now()
   End If
     Set R1 = Nothing
     Set R2 = Nothing
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Target.Row to determine the row, so you could just use:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Column < 31 And Target.Column <> 24 Then
    Cells(Target.Row, 24) = Now()
End If

End Sub
```